# Noch eine Frage zu winzig Adjektiv vs Adverb

Tags: adverb

In diesem Fall ist "winzig" eindeutig ein Adjektiv, das die Kleinheit des Raums hervorhebt, nicht das Verb, das leicht "gedrückt" bedeuten würde. Warum sollte es nicht winzigen sein?

> Unsere Welt könnte demnach aus einem vorhergehenden Universum
>   entstanden sein, das sich unter seinem eigenen Gewicht kontrahiert
>   hat, bis es, in einen **winzig** kleinen Raum zusammengedrückt, wieder
>   «zurückgeprallt» ist, sich erneut ausgedehnt hat und so zu dem
>   expandierenden Universum wurde, das wir um uns herum beobachten.

Das muss ein Fehler sein.

Comment: Ich kann da keinen Fehler entdecken.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ es kann sich auch nicht auf kleine beziehen, also ist es ein Adjektiv, das dekliniert werden muss

Comment: _ein **winzig** kleiner Raum_ ist perfektes Deutsch.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Warum? Das letzte Mal wurde winzig nicht dekliniert, weil es ein Adverb war. Hier ist es eindeutig ein Adjektiv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Der Satz ist völlig korrekt.
2. Das Wort *winzig* ist immer ein Adjektiv, es ist niemals ein Adverb.
3. Die Beugung von Adjektiven hängt davon ab, worauf sie sich beziehen.

Als erstes räume ich mal mit einer Unklarheit auf, die ich häufig beobachte, und die sich vor allem bei den Adverbien und Adjektiven manifestiert:

Es gibt Wortarten und es gibt grammatische Funktionen. Und das sind zwei völlig verschiedene Dinge. Ein Wort gehört einer bestimmten Wortart an, egal wo im Satz es steht. Es ist sogar egal, ob es überhaupt in irgend einem Gefüge steht oder ganz allein, z.B. als Überschrift eines Eintrags in einem Wörterbuch.

Das Wort *»Butter«* ist immer ein Substantiv, das Wort »*fahren«* ist immer ein Verb, das Wort *»schnell«* ist immer ein Adjektiv und das Wort *»gern«* ist immer ein Adverb. Jedes Wort gehört immer genau einer Wortart an, egal wo dieses Wort vorkommt. (Eine Ergänzung für Homonyme steht am Ende meiner Antwort.)

Davon strikt zu trennen ist die grammatische Funktion, die ein Wort (oder eine Gruppe von Wörtern) in einem Satz inne hat.

Adjektive werden in diesen Funktionen verwendet:

1. Attribut eines Substantivs

   > die **schöne** Blume
   >   die **rote** Lampe
   >   der **winzige** Raum

   In diesem Fall müssen die Adjektive gebeugt werden (nach Geschlecht, Zahl und Bestimmtheit)
2. Attribut eines Adjektivs oder Partizips

   > die **schön** blühende Blume
   >   die **rot** leuchtende Lampe
   >   der **winzig** kleine Raum

   Attribute von Adjektiven und Partizipien werden nicht gebeugt.
3. Prädikativ (durch ein Kopula an das Subjekt des Satzes gebunden)

   > Die Blume wird **schön.**
   >   Die Lampe ist **rot.**
   >   Der Raum bleibt **winzig.**

   Prädikative werden nicht gebeugt.
4. Adverbial (nachgestelltes Attribut eines Verbs)

   > Die Blume blüht **schön.**
   >   Die Lampe leuchtet **rot.**
   >   Der Raum wirkt **winzig.**

   Adverbiale werden nicht gebeugt.

Adverbien können nur adverbial (als nachgestelltes Attribut eines Verbs) verwendet werden, nicht aber als Prädikativ oder Attribut eines Substantivs. Die Verwendung als Attribut eines Adjektivs oder Partizips ist hingegen möglich.

> - Die Blume blüht **vielleicht.** (richtig, adverbial verwendetes Adverb)
> - <del>Die Blume ist **vielleicht.**</del> (falsch, prädikativ verwendetes Adverb)
> - <del>die **vielleichte** Blume</del> (falsch, Attribut eines Substantivs)
> - die **vielleicht** blühende Blume (richtig, Attribut eines Partizips)

---

Noch ein paar Beispiele:

- > der **winzige** Raum
  >   der **kleine** Raum

  Hier ist klar, dass sich das Adjektiv auf das Substantiv bezieht.
- > der **winzige, kleine** Raum

  Hier beziehen sich beide Adjektive auf das Substantiv daher werden beide gebeugt. Der Raum ist klein und zugleich ist er auch winzig. Da die bieden Attribute gleichrangig sind, und *»kleiner Raum«* kein Gesamtbegriff ist, muss hier auch ein Komma stehen.

  <sup>Bei *»frischer holländischer Käse«* sind *»frischer«* und *»holländischer«* nicht gleichrangig. *»Holländischer Käse«* ist ein Gesamtbegriff, daher wirkt *»frischer«* nicht auf *»Käse«* allein, sondern auf *»holländischer Käse«* und deswegen darf man kein Komma setzen. In *»winziger, kleiner Raum«* sind *»winziger«* und *»kleiner«* aber gleichrangig. Das Wort *»winziger«* wirkt nur auf *»Raum«*, nicht aber auf *»kleiner Raum«*. Daher muss in diesem Fall ein Komma stehen. Das kann man auch durch Vertauschen der Attribute austesten: *»holländischer frischer Käse«* wäre falsch (weil sich hier ein Attribut zwischen zwei Bestandteile eines Gesamtbegriffs drängt), aber *»kleiner, winziger Raum«* wäre in Ordnung (weil beide Adjektive gleichrangig sind, und keines fester an das Substantiv gebunden ist als das andere).</sup>
- > der **winzig kleine** Raum

  Hier bezieht sich nur das Wort *»klein«* direkt auf das Substantiv: Der Raum ist klein, aber der Raum ist nicht winzig.
  Das Wort *»winzig«* ist ein Attribut des Adjektivs *»klein«*. Es beschriebt die Art der Kleinheit, es beschreibt aber nicht direkt eine Eigenschaft des Raums. Indirekt wirkt aber das Wort *»winzig«* natürlich sehr wohl auch auf den Raum, aber eben nur indirekt, indem es es die Kleinheit noch weiter verkleinert.

---

<sub>Noch eine Ergänzung zur Wortart:</sub>

<sub>Eine Besonderheit sind Homonyme, das sind Wörter, die gleich geschrieben werden und gleich gesprochen werden, aber verschiedene Bedeutung haben. z.B.</sub>

> <sub>Er wird bald bei dir **sein.** (Verb)</sub>
>   <sub>Er ist **sein** Vater. (Pronomen)</sub>

<sub>Die beiden Instanzen von »*sein«* sind nicht dasselbe Wort, Das sind zwei verschiedene Wörter, die zufällig gleich geschrieben und gesprochen werden.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Winzig in deinem Sazt modifiziert und verstärkt das Wort "klein", und nicht das Nomen "Raum" direkt. Dazu kann man die Frage mit dem Fragewort "wie" stellen:

> - Wie klein? Winzig klein. (In einem winzig kleinen Raum)
> - vgl. Wie groß? Riesig groß.  (in einem riesig großen Raum)

Comment: OK but that doesn't fit in the context. The point is it's really really small. You're saying it means a kinda little space right? A little bit small? The two are opposites.

Comment: No, quite the opposite, this amplifies and further reinforces the idea of smallness. Makes it even more stronger. Think of it as a more literary and elegant way of saying "very" or "extremely" even.
We may loosely compare it to some pidgin languages where "very quick" would be expressed as "quick quick".

Comment: The way to weaken the "klein" would be a different one... Namely saying "in einem etwas kleinen Raum".